# The d-neighborhood of the k-mer Pattern is the collection of all k-mers that are at most Hamming distance d from Pattern

Tags: python, bioinformatics

The d-neighborhood of the k-mer Pattern is the collection of all k-mers that are at most Hamming distance d from Pattern.

How many 4-mers are in the 3-neighborhood of Pattern = ACGT?

Note that the d-neighborhood of Pattern includes Pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should not ask homework questions on stack overflow as they are very specific and won't help others. I won't give you a copy & paste solution but here is how I would solve this:

1. Write a function to calculate the hamming distance between two patterns

This can be done by iterating over one pattern and then comparing the value with the value at the same position in the other pattern and increasing a counter if the values don't match like so:

```
def hamming_distance(pattern_1, pattern_2):
    for idx, c in enumerate(pattern_1):
        if c != pattern_2[idx]:
            # increase a counter
    return counter
```

2. Generate all 4-mers

Next, you need to generate all 4-mers that you want to check. For this, you can use the itertools product

```
itertools.product("AGCT", repeat=4)
```

You then need to join the combinations to strings you can compare with the function written above. Maybe, you also need to do some filtering for combinations that don't exist in nature.

3. Count all 4-mers in 3-neighborhood

Finally, loop over all the generated combinations and calculate the hamming distance with the reference pattern. If it is less than or equal to 3, increase a counter. Then print the counter and you are done!

```
reference_pattern = "ACGT"
counter = 0
for pattern in generate_all_k_mers(k=4):
    if hamming_distance(reference_pattern, pattern) <= 3:
        counter += 1
print(f"{counter} patterns are in the 3-neighborhood of {reference_pattern}")
```

Good luck!